# Prove that $f$ has a simple zero in $0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)= \displaystyle\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{nz^n}{1-z^n}}$. Prove that $f$ has a simple zero in $z_0=0$.

I already prove that $f$ is analytic over the open disc $D_1(0)$. So, as $f(0)=0$, then exist a open set $U$, such that $f(z)=z^mg(z)$  for all $z\in U$. But this do not help to decide the order of the zero.

By the other hand, using the Taylor series, $f(z)=\displaystyle\sum _{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k$, with $
a_k=\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} $.

So, its enougth to prove that $f(0)=0$, (clear) and $f'(0)\neq0$.

Then i did this:
By a theorem in my class, if a sequence of holomorphic funtion $g_n \rightarrow g$
uniformly, then $g'_n \rightarrow g'$, thus,

$$f'(z)=\dfrac{d}{dz} \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nz^n}{1-z^n}= \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dz} \frac{nz^n}{1-z^n}= \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2z^{n-1}}{(1-z^n)^2}=\dfrac{1}{(1-z)^2}+ \dfrac{4z}{(1-z^2)^2}+\cdots$$ then $f'(0)=1$ then
$$f(z)=\displaystyle\sum _{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k=0 + z +a_2z^2+\cdots=zh(z)$$
where $h(0)\neq 0$, holomorphic, finally

$$\dfrac{1}{f}=z^{-1}g(z)$$

Then $f$ has a simple zero in $z=0$.

Is sufficiently argued?

Comment: Do you mean a simple zero?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking in $1/f$. I will edit it.